# Vacuum leak above brake pedal

Tags: ford, brakes, mercury, grand-marquis, vacuum-hoses

1988 Mercury Colony Park - 302 engine/AOD transmission -

Found a vacuum leak right above my brake pedal, I have no idea what these hoses go to and what they do (although I assume its associated with the brake booster.)

The hissing fluctuates a little whenever I shift to Drive or overdrive, the hissing then dissipates whenever I step on the gas and builds back up when throttle is released.

I removed the black vacuum line as pointed out in the pic, the then stops. I'm guessing there is a crack in the white half ring the lines hook up to. 
Also im not sure if there is a third line im not seeing that could be unhooked.

Does anyone know what the cause is, and where I could get a replacement piece?
 [image]

[image]

Comment: What's the number on the part? The arrow obscures it.

Answer (score 2):

I had an '86 Town Car (same platform) back in the day. IIRC, the white half ring is the automatic parking brake release. When mine leaked, I removed the vacuum line and plugged it. That took care of the leak, but I didn't have the automatic release feature anymore. You would want to source a replacement part in order to regain full functionality.